# Generating Functions for Posets

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions

I'm attempting to solve exercise 46(b) in *Stanley's Enumerative Combinatorics Volume 1*. The problem is stated as follows:

Let $g(n)$ be the number of sublattices of $B_{n}$ that contain $\varnothing$ and $[n]$ and let $f(n)$ be the number of rank $n$ sublattices of the boolean algebra $B_{n}$ (or equivalently the number of partial orders $P$ on $[n]$). Write
$$F(x) = \sum_{n \ge 0}f(n)\frac{x^{n}}{n!}$$
$$G(x) = \sum_{n \ge 0}g(n)\frac{x^{n}}{n!}$$
Show that $G(x) = F(e^{x}-1)$

My Attempt:
Clearly
$$F(e^{x}-1) = \sum_{n \ge 0}f(n)\frac{(e^{x}-1)^{n}}{n!}$$
which is the $e^{e^{x}-1}$ generating function of $f(n)$. It is know that
$$e^{e^{x}-1} = \sum_{n \ge 0}b(n)\frac{x^{n}}{n!}$$
where $b(n)$ is the $n$th bell number. It then follows
$$F(e^{x}-1) = \sum_{n \ge 0}f(n)b(n)\frac{x^{n}}{n!}$$
so we need show that $f(n)b(n) = g(n)$ for all $n$.

The problem I'm having is that $f(n)b(n) = g(n)$ fails for $n = 2$ so I went wrong somewhere. $f(2) = 3$ and $b(2) = 2$ but $g(2) = 4$. Am I proceeding in the right direction to solve this problem or am I missing a key element in the proof?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've noted, it does not follow that $F(e^x - 1) = \sum f(n)b(n) x^n/n!$.

Think combinatorially about what the formula $G(x) = F(e^x - 1)$ tells you. The function $e^x - 1$ is the generating function for non-empty sets. Composing $F$ with $e^x - 1$ tells you to take $[n]$ and partition it into non-empty sets $[n] = S_1 \sqcup \cdots \sqcup S_k$ ($\sqcup =$ disjoint union) then take a sub-lattice of $B_k$ labeled with $S_1, \dots, S_k$.

How might we find such a decomposition? Given a lattice $L$ we want to find $S_1,\dots,S_k$. Note that $k$ must be the rank of $L$ (by definition of $f(k)$). So take a maximal chain $\mathcal C$ in $L$. We can write $\mathcal C$ as

$$ \emptyset \subset S_1 \subset S_1 \sqcup S_2 \subset \dots \subset S_1 \sqcup S_2 \sqcup \dots \sqcup S_k = [n]. $$

I believe this gives you $S_1, \dots, S_k$.

Comment: I understand your argument but what if $L$ is a lattice with incomparable elements, say $B_{2}$? By your argument we cant take the sublattice of $B_{2}$ that is $B_{2}$ and label it with $S_{1},\ldots,S_{k}$ since our partition would consist of $2$ sets but our sublattice has $4$ elements.

Comment: @Twiss013 There are two maximal chains in $B_2$, namely $\emptyset \subset \{1\} \subset \{1,2\}$ and $\emptyset \subset \{2\} \subset \{1,2\}$. This gives $\{S_1, S_2\} = \{\{1\}, \{2\}\}$, right? Now we put a lattice structure on the set of finite unions of $\{\{1\}, \{2\}\}$ (which is all of $\mathcal{P}(\{1,2\})$ namely the full lattice $B_2$.

Comment: For a slightly more complicated example, consider partitioning $\{1,2,3,4\}$ into $\{1,2\}$ and $\{3,4\}$. Then form the lattice where $\{1,2\}$ and $\{3,4\}$ are atoms and $\{1,2\} \vee \{3,4\} = \{1,2,3,4\}$ and $\{1,2\} \wedge \{3,4\} = \emptyset$.

Comment: Ah, I understand now!

Comment: @TrevorGunn I'm having some trouble understanding how the lattices in $B_k$ correspond to sublattices of $B_n$. If n=3 and L= {1,2,3}, {1, 3}, {2, 3}, {2}, {} , what would the rank $k$ sublattice of $B_k$ look like?

Comment: @Mauve It's been 2 years so bear with me. Based on what I said, we take a maximal chain in $L$. In this case $\varnothing \subset \{2\} \subset \{2,3\} \subset \{1,2,3\}$. Here $S_1 = \{2\}, S_2 = \{3\}, S_3 = \{1\}$. Then the lattice structure of all finite unions of $S_1, S_2, S_3$ is all of $B_3$ with $S_1, S_2, S_3$ serving as atoms. You get something more interesting if you start with a lattice of rank less than $n$.

Comment: I mean $S_1, S_2, S_3$ gives you the atoms of a $B_k$ and then $L$ is an appropriate sublattice of $B_k$. Not necessarily the whole lattice. If $L$ had rank $n$ to begin with, you should just get $L$ at the end of the construction. The point is just to group some of the atoms together if the rank is less than $n$.

Comment: @TrevorGunn Sublattices counted by f in $B_k$ are graded since they all have rank $n$, but there are some lattices in $B_n$ counted by g that are not graded (like {1,2,3}, {1, 3}, {2, 3}, {2}, {} ). I understand how you're finding S_1, S_2,..., S_k from a given lattice $L$, but I'm having trouble seeing the correspondence between sublattices of $B_n$ and fixed-rank- k sublattices

Comment: @Mauve The point is that if you have elements that always appear together, like if $1 \in S$ iff $2 \in S$, then you  can embed the lattice inside a smaller $B_k$ where you replace $1$ and $2$ by $\{1,2\}$. But I don't want to hash out a problem that I haven't though about in 2 years in the comments. Create a new question if you need to.

Comment: Will do. Thanks for entertaining my questions for a while.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3469192 for more on this.